# remove <p> background via css

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where I can't seem to get rid of the background colour of a p tag, is it possible to do this? I have set the divs backgrounds to images.

**Output:**

[image]

CSS

```
   .box {
display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: -1px; text-align: left; padding: 25px;
}    
#tables {
max-width: 1080px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
#screenshots {
background: url(http://i.cubeupload.com/nAtNKD.jpg) no-repeat center;
width: 308px;
height: 280px;
}
#csmatches {
background: url(http://i.cubeupload.com/nAtNKD.jpg) no-repeat center;
width: 308px;
height: 280px;
}
#fixtures {
background: url(http://i.cubeupload.com/nAtNKD.jpg) no-repeat center;
width: 308px;
height: 280px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="tables">

<div id="screenshots" class="box">Screenshots</div>

<div id="csmatches" class="box"><p>Recent Match Results</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="fixtures" class="box">Fixtures</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code please?

Comment: Please post the `HTML` and `CSS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#csmatches p {
    background:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the background of the p use:

```
.your-p-class {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

or for all of them:

```
.container p {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/3waTE/

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I have my body background set to #333, this is probably where it is getting the colour from however when setting a class for the P it still pulls the body colour instead of adapting to the background image

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this :

```
.mycontainer p {
    background-color:none;
}
```

It seems like you have set a background color attribute to your div and its children...